# Force Compass to use .sass syntax?

Tags: compass-sass

Is there a way to force Compass to use the Sass syntax instead of SCSS?

Comment: I found it myself: --syntax sass

Comment: You should close or mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **new projects**, run:

`compass create path/to/project --syntax sass`

to generate .sass files using Sass syntax inside the sass folder. The `--syntax` option and others are listed when you run `compass --help`.

For **existing projects**, add the following to your Compass config.rb:

`preferred_syntax = :sass`

That's covered in the [Compass configuration reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/). And you'll want to run your existing SCSS files through `sass-convert` to generate new ones which use Sass syntax.